# What should be the tense in this reported speech?

Tags: reported-speech

How to make this sentence better:

> I said to him that if he wanted to say something,now would be the good
>   time

Answer (score 1):

Past tense for "said", and "now would be" are fine and no changes need to be made where tense is concerned.

In terms of improving the sentence in all, here are a few tips:

---

**"I told him"**

It isn't common to use the phrase "*[subj]* said to *[ind.obj]* that *[clause]*". In natural speech "said" or "to say" is often followed immediately by what is said, rather than the indirect object. Luckily however, there is another verb for that:

> **to tell** *[someone] [something]* - to say [something] to [someone]
>
> - **Plural:** tells,
> - **Singular:** tell
>
> **E.g.**
>
> - I *tell* him that he is kind.
> - She *tells* John the time.
> - The boys *tell* the teacher lies.
>
> **More Forms**
>
> - **Past:** told
> - **Present Participle:** telling
> - **Past Participle:** told

---

**The vs. A**

It may take me a while to fully figure out why this is the case, however it is simply a natural thing for me at the moment. Saying "now is the good time" is an unnatural phrasing because of your use of "the". Try one of these alternatives instead:

- now is the best time.
- now is a good time.
- now is the time.